# Почему не выходит использовать данные одного класса в другом?

Tags: java

```
import uga.rand;
public class body {
    public static int main(String [] args) {
    int x = 1;
    double que = 0;
    boolean isRight = false;
    double target = (double) (Math.random() * 10);
    System.out.println("Я загадываю " + target);
    while(true)
    {
    que = new uga.rand();
    System.out.println("Я думаю это " + que);
    if(que==target)
    {
        System.out.println("Угадал!");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("еще");
    x=x+1;
    }
    
}
    return(x);
}
}
```

второй

```
public class uga {
    double number = 0;
    public double rand () {
    number = (double) Math.random();
    return(number);
}
}
```

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\java!\1\body.java:1: error: package uga does not exist
> import uga.rand;
> ^
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\java!\1\body.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
> que = new uga.rand();
> ^
> symbol:   class rand
> location: class uga
> 2 errors

Comment: Ошибка прямо говорит, что у Вас нет пакета uga.random. Попробуйте оставить только "import uga".

Comment: Спасибо, но ошибка была немного в другом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая ошибка говорит что нет пакета `uga`, поэтому импорт не компилируется.

Если оба класса находится в одном пакете, то импорт не требуется.

---

Вторая ошибка связана с классом `rand`, который не существует. У ваc синтаксическая ошибка, так как вы пытаетесь создать экземпляр класса `uga`, а вместо этого указали имя класса  `rand` в пакете `uga`.

Попробуйте так

```
new uga().rand();
```

или же

```
uga u = new uga();
que = u.rand();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое